# how to custom a android layout contains two Button and one EditText .The layout can move around everywhere in screen

Tags: android, android-edittext

now i have to make a android EditText moving and rotating on screen.So i use and LinerLayout,anh Put two button and one EditText in.The LinerLayout can not move and drag on screen.so I want to custom a  layout class That can move and rotate on it own parent.are there anyone can help me!,please send me a sample ,if u can.Thanks u so much

Comment: show us what you have tried ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for moving a text on screen (Only for API level greater or equal to 11)

```
 final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        tv.setTranslationX(tv.getTranslationX() + 10);
        tv.setTranslationY(tv.getTranslationY() + 10);
        tv.invalidate();
```